# How to add where clause in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am very new to elasticsearch. I have an elastic search query which returns all users present in database based on keyword but here I need to get only the users whose active status is true but now I am getting all list of users.

I have built a search query like

```
    {
        "from" : 0,
        "size" : 30,
        "query" : {
            "query_string" : {
                "query" : "*jhon*",
                "default_field" : "_all"
            }
        },
        "sort" : [ 
            {
                "id" : {
                    "order" : "desc"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am using a query like `*jhon*`, but I need to get result like users with name `jhon` and his active status should be true, so  I have tried `*"+jhon+"\*"#activated~true"` but I am not getting the desired result.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's best to add a filter to your query. Filters are faster since they don't involve any scoring and are cached. There are different filters that you can use, the elasticsearch query DSL is really flexible. The kind of filters depends on the way you indexed data, which depends on your data. I'll assume the easiest possbile solution: a [term filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-filter/). Have a look at the following example.

```
{
    "from" : 0,
    "size" : 30,
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "*jhon*",
            "default_field" : "_all"
        }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "term" : { 
            "activated" : "true" 
        }
    },
    "sort" : [ 
        {
            "id" : {
                "order" : "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Beware that there are different ways to apply filters when searching. In my example I applied a top level filter, which will only be applied to the search results, and not to the facets. If you want it to be applied to the facets too, you should have a look at the [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query/); instead of adding a filter you would wrap your current query into  new filtered query, which can also contain the same term filter.